# Creating an association list with element evaluation

Tags: elisp

So as far as I understand it you create association lists that look like

```
'((rose . red)
 (violet . violet)
 (chrysanthemum . who-knows))
```

My question is, what do you do if you want `rose`, `violet`, etc., to be evaluated before they're put into the alist?

For example, for normal lists you can do

```
(list 1 2 3 4)
```

instead of

```
'(1 2 3 4)
```

How do you replicate this functionality? I'm new to elisp and Emacs, so please forgive any errors or misnomers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(list (cons rose red)
      (cons violet violet)
      (cons chrysanthemum who-knows))
```

each flower should be bound to a value.

Answer (score 3):

An alist is just a list.  So, you can use all the normal list-constructing functions like `cons` or `list`.  Or, if you want to write one that looks like a constant, you can use backquote:

```
`((,(rose) . red)
  (,(violet) . violet))
```

This will evaluate `rose` and `violet` at construction time and substitute the results.

Comment: Or if `rose` is a variable: `,rose`.